# Trying to upload and play video in laravel 4.

Tags: laravel

So i wanted to upload and play a video in my views but when i try to upload a video.mp4 i get this error and i dont know if it will play in my views. when i try uploading a video i get this error. Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object

What should i do? i mean how can i upload a video and play it im my views.blade.php

so here is my controller that uploads the image/video

```
$image = Input::file('image');
        var_dump($image->getRealPath());
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        //saving image to public folder
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('150', '150')->save('public/img/' .$filename);
        $users = Auth::user();

        //saving image to database
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));
        $post->image = $filename;

        $users->post()->save($post);

        return Redirect::route('profile', array('id' => $users->id));
```

and this is the my view.blade.php where i upload the file

```
@section('content') 

    <div class="create-post">
        {{Form::open(array('url' => 'Newpost', 'files' => 'true', 'method' => 'post'))}}

            {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title')}}<br>

            {{Form::label('content', 'Content')}}
            {{Form::textarea('content')}}

            <br>
            {{Form::file('image')}}
            {{Form::submit('Publish')}}

        {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: If you var_dump($image) only, show you the object info?

Comment: nope it doenst work instead it returns this error Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a file that is larger than the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` the Input::file('image') returns null, for a workaround with this try to evaluate first if is null like this:

```php
<?php

$image = Input::file('image');
if($image) {
    var_dump($image->getRealPath());
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    //saving image to public folder
    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('150', '150')->save('public/img/' .$filename);
    $users = Auth::user();

    //saving image to database
    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = Input::get('title');
    $post->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));
    $post->image = $filename;

    $users->post()->save($post);

    return Redirect::route('profile', array('id' => $users->id));
}
```

Then if null show an errror message.

This works, but is strongly recommended implementing a [file size validation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-size) in your code.

I hope wokrs for you.